# Jquery AJAX 404 form.php not found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to wire up a simple HTML form using Jquery and PHP. However, I'm running into the following error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8887/form.php 404 (Not Found)
```

**script.js**

```
$("#form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }).validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      subject: {
        required: true,
      },
      message: {
        required: true,
      },
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
      // alert("enter");
      var form = $('#form');
      var formData = $(form).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../form.php',
        data: formData
      }).done(function (response) {
        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
      });

      return false;  //This doesn't prevent the form from submitting.
    }
  });
```

**Directory structure:**

```
16/07/2018  03:22 AM    <DIR>          .
16/07/2018  03:22 AM    <DIR>          ..
23/06/2018  05:48 PM    <DIR>          .git
14/05/2018  03:37 PM                11 .gitignore
21/06/2018  03:00 PM    <DIR>          .sass-cache
14/05/2018  03:09 PM    <DIR>          .vscode
21/06/2018  03:00 PM    <DIR>          bulma
14/05/2018  03:09 PM    <DIR>          content
14/05/2018  03:09 PM    <DIR>          css
16/07/2018  03:22 AM                66 form.php
15/07/2018  06:57 PM    <DIR>          img
16/07/2018  03:03 AM            31,166 index.html
12/05/2018  07:55 PM                45 index.php
15/07/2018  06:57 PM    <DIR>          js
16/07/2018  03:22 AM    <DIR>          php
27/05/2018  12:16 PM               378 README.md
```

the `js` folder consist of the `script.js` file which that calls for `form.php` in the directory. How do I correctly point the `ajax` script to the correct php file? If it helps, I'm using the Chrome Webserver plugin to emulate a webserver since Chrome does not allow php scripts from opening `index.html` as files.

Comment: just use form.php and chech it once

Comment: are you using any framework?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a issue with chrome web server, I am not sure if it can handle php files and serve it.

Try to server your form.php with the php built in server:

inside your directory structure execute:

```
php -S localhost:80
```

Then, change the URL from your jquery script:

```
  submitHandler: function () {
      // alert("enter");
      var form = $('#form');
      var formData = $(form).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/form.php',
        data: formData
      }).done(function (response) {
        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
      });

      return false;  //This doesn't prevent the form from submitting.
    }
```